# UIContextMenuInteraction : How to Dismiss Manually?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, contextmenu

When a UIContextMenuInteraction/UITargetedPreview is visible, is it possible to manually dismiss it? For example, when the app goes to the background, I would like to dismiss it manually.

https://kylebashour.com/posts/context-menu-guide

Answer (score 3):

`UIContextMenuInteraction` has a method which is called `dismissMenu`.

I believe this is what you would rather call when in need to hide a menu, because calling `dismiss(animated:completion:)` could lead to unwanted behaviour if you have another modally presented controller and you are not sure if the menu is active.

Moreover, starting from iOS 13.2 you can get access to `contextMenuInteraction` as a property of a `UICollectionView` and call `dismissMenu`.

`contextMenuInteraction` is also available as a property for a `UITableView` starting from iOS 14.0

It becomes quite complicated when your minimal iOS version is 13.0 and you need somehow to dismiss a menu for a cell in a collectionView. This is a bump in the road I am currently having trouble with. I believe the only appropriate way is to create, save and provide a custom PreviewViewController in this method:

```
collectionView(collectionView: contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt: point:) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration?
```

When having access to your custom PreviewViewController, you can call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` method on it whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was interested in the same thing, and calling `UIViewController.dismiss(animated:completion:)` on the source view controller dismisses it as it would a modally presented controller.

Comment: This helped me. I am not sure if it's the proper way of doing it, but it works fine when I call willResignActive. BTW, when the app is going to background is the only time you want to dismiss the context menu programmatically, because the user has the control at this point.